# SpringBoot LDAPTemplate Embedded vs Real LDAP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-ldap

I am using the below mentioned properties in my SpringBoot App, in `application.yml` file to have the LDAP Code run in my local machine.

```
spring:
  ldap:
    # Use this embedded configuration for local ldap testing
    embedded:
      base-dn: o=localcompany,c=US
      credential:
        username: uid=admin
        password: secret
      ldif: classpath:schemas.ldif
      port: 12345
      validation:
        enabled: false
    # Use this below configuration for Ford ldap
#    urls: ldaps://mmm.mmm.com:754
#    base-dn: o=****,c=US
#    username: 
#    password: {your password goes here}
```

I want to have both my embedded configuration & actual configuration exist in my Application, so that it works locally as well as in my Cloud Environment. But having Embedded properties in my yml file is overwriting the actual ones even in Cloud Environment. Is there a way to have both the properties and then according to the Environment, wire the `LDAPTemplate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I configured my LDAPTemplate using `@profile` annotation that would differentiate the local and Server environment and achieved what I asked above. Below is my configuration. For the Local environment, having the embedded-properties are sufficient to have `LDAPTemplate` wired properly

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;

@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class LDAPConfiguration {

    @Value("${ldap.url}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Value("${ldap.base}")
    private String ldapBase;

    @Value("${ldap.username}")
    private String ldapUser;

    @Value("${ldap.password}")
    private String ldapPassword;

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate configureLdapTemplateForCloud() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource()) ;
    }

    private LdapContextSource contextSource() {

        LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();

        ldapContextSource.setUrl(ldapUrl);
        ldapContextSource.setBase(ldapBase);
        ldapContextSource.setUserDn(ldapUser);
        ldapContextSource.setPassword(ldapPassword);

        ldapContextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return ldapContextSource;
    }

}
```

So now, when I run in my local, Spring Boot will play with my Embedded LDAP, but in the cloud profile, it will execute the actual LDAP Server.